# Phantom Scala Cassandra connector: how to specify port, username, password of nodes

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I'm trying to use websudos [phantom](https://github.com/websudos/phantom)

Does anyone know how to specify connection arguments to Cassandra such as username and password?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phantom doesn't yet support Kerberos authentication in the `phantom-connectors` framework but it is on the roadmap for the coming weeks.

However, when using connectors it is possible to override the `createCluster` method and connect to the cluster in any way you want.

```
object CustomCassandraManger extends DefaultCasandraManager {

  override protected[this] def createCluster: Cluster = {
    val inets = hosts.toSeq.map(_.getAddress)

    Cluster.builder()
     .addContactPoints(inets: _*)
     ...
     .withUsernameAndPassword(..)
  }
}
```

I may not have used the correct methods, but that's how you control the way a cluster is created. Then all you need is to inject this manager in a connector:

```
trait MyConnector extends SimpleCassandraConnector {
  override val manager = CustomCassandraMananger
}
```

And then you mix in this connector into all your tables, just as you would normally when using phantom.

**Recent versions of phantom**

In more recent versions of phantom, the API is based on `ContactPoints`, where you can specify whatever `ClusterBuilder` options you want, using the following DSL.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.PlainTextAuthProvider

lazy val local = ContactPoint.local.withClusterBuilder(
  _.withAuthProvider(new PlainTextAuthProvider("user", "pass"))
).keySpace("phantom")
```